# python string find function doesn't give position from text returned by beautifulsoup

Tags: python, string, beautifulsoup, find

I am trying to scrape a section of 10-K filings. I am having a problem to identify the postion of 'item 7(a).' from text returned by beautifulsoup inspite of having the word in it. But the following code is working for a string I made that contains 'item 7(a).'

```
import urllib2
import re
import bs4 as bs
url=https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1580608/000158060817000015/santander201610-k.htm'

html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf8')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
text = soup.get_text()
text = text.encode('utf-8')
text = text.lower()
print type(text)
print len(text)
text1 = "hf dfbd item 7. abcd sfjsdf sdbfjkds item 7(a). adfbdf item 8. skjfbdk item 7. sdfkba ootgf sffdfd item 7(a). sfbdskf sfdf item 8. sdfbksdf "
print text.find('item 7(a)')
print text1.find('item 7(a)')

Output:
<type 'str'>
592214
-1
37
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Are you using python2 by any chance?

Comment: Yes. I am using Python 2.7. I also tried in Python 3.6 but I got the same result.

Comment: did you display `text` ? Maybe server gives you different result that in web browser.

Comment: I printed text. The string "item 7(a)." is in it.

Comment: I ran a few tests. Nothing wrong with your code here. Paste a snapshot of your "text" maybe? What is the index where it is actually present?

Comment: Please find the image here. https://i.stack.imgur.com/dP8Yg.png

Comment: I found `item` and `7(a)` and I used `ord()` to test chars and it seems it uses char with code `160` as space between `item` and `7(a)` - it is not standard space with code `32`

Comment: I understand the problem. Thanks a lot for it pointing out. Is there any work around?

Comment: I found code `160` is for entity `&nbsp;` (Not Breaking SPace)

Comment: you can run `replace(chr(160), " ")` to replace all chars with code `160` into normal space.

Answer (score 0):

Page uses entity `&nbsp;` (**N**ot **B**reaking **SP**ace) (with char code `160`)
instead of normal space (code `32`) in text `ITEM 7(A)`

You can replace all chars with code `160` (`chr(160)`) with normal space (`" "`).
In Python 2 (after encoding) you have to replace two chars - `194` and `160`

```
text = text.replace(chr(160), " ") # Python 3
text = text.replace(char(194)+chr(160), " ") # Python 2
```

Full example

```
#import urllib.request as urllib2 # Python 3
import urllib2
import re
import bs4 as bs

url='https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1580608/000158060817000015/santander201610-k.htm'

html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf8')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
text = soup.get_text()
text = text.encode('utf-8') # only Python 2
text = text.lower()

#text = text.replace(chr(160), " ") # Python 3
text = text.replace(char(194)+chr(160), " ") # Python 2

search = 'item 7(a)'

# find every occurence in text    
pos = 0
while True:
    pos = text.find(search, pos)
    if pos == -1:
        break
    #print(pos, ">"+text[pos-1]+"<", ord(text[pos-1]))
    print(text[pos:pos+20])
    pos += 1
```

**EDIT:** tested only with Python 3

You can search string `'item&nbsp;7(a)'` after unescaping it.
But you would have to know that you have to use `&nbsp;` instead of `" "` in this place.

```
from html import unescape

search = unescape('item&nbsp;7(a)')
```

Full code

```
#import urllib.request as urllib2 # Python 3
import urllib2
import re
import bs4 as bs

url='https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1580608/000158060817000015/santander201610-k.htm'

html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf8')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
text = soup.get_text()
text = text.lower()

from html import unescape

search = unescape('item&nbsp;7(a)')

# find every occurence in text    
pos = 0
while True:
    pos = text.find(search, pos)
    if pos == -1:
        break
    #print(pos, ">"+text[pos-1]+"<", ord(text[pos-1]))
    print(text[pos:pos+20])
    pos += 1
```